# how I install pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I have face with this problem wheni tries to install pandas library.[image]

Comment: Seems like You have already installed `pandas`

Comment: yeah but i can not import it

Comment: I think you have installed it on python 3.9. But seems like VS code uses python 3.10(See right bottom). May be you will be able to change the version by clicking on 3.10.

Comment: pandas is installed my problem is for importing that i face with this message"import "pandas" could not be resolved from source  Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)